# python how can I generate new random numbers each time a loop iterates?

Tags: python

I coded a little math quiz that I need to insert in a loop (while..)
to make it iterates a new time a user wants to.
Especially, how do I make it generate ''new random numbers'' each time it iterates.
I know I can insert a control variable such as keep_going = y
to let user decide whether to continue or not.

Please see codes below, and thanks for the help!

```
import random

first_num = random.randint(1,500)
second_num = random.randint(1,500)

print (first_num)
print (second_num)

answer = int(input('Entrer la somme des deux nombres: '))

if answer == first_num + second_num:
    print("It's correct!")

else:
    print("It's wrong!")
```

Comment: Your quotation marks in the `print` functions/statements are a little messed up.

Comment: I agree with @mgilson re: formatting, but ummm, a remarkably boring quiz? And what if I entered just `0 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a [while loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop).  This one will loop forever until the user gets the question right, but you could put any condition after `while` that might eventually be false.

Then I use `raw_input()` to have the user determine whether or not to continue.  This is one of many ways to accomplish what you're going for.

```
import random

while True:

    first_num = random.randint(1,500)
    second_num = random.randint(1,500)

    print (first_num)
    print (second_num)

    answer = int(input('Entrer la somme des deux nombres: '))

    if answer == first_num + second_num:
        print("It's correct!")
        break
    else:
        print("It's wrong!")
        tryAgain = raw_input('Try again? [(y)/n] ')
        if tryAgain.lower() == 'n':
            break
```

Comment: Hi! thanks! I use Python 3.3 so instead of raw_input I typed "input(..)". Your codes helped me a lot! I tweaked them a bit to get the program to always ask "shall we continue".